# error: invalid conversion from 'QRadioButton*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, qt, callback, radio-button, signals-slots

I am trying to connect a signal and slot in Qt. It seems to be the same I've done previosuly untill I saw this error. I am unable to figure out why. Any Help Appreciated.

**error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'const sockaddr*' for argument '2' to 'int connect(int, const sockaddr*, socklen_t)'
       connect(x_13, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(disp1()));**

This is my .h file

```
    QRadioButton*    x_13;
    QRadioButton*    x_14;
    QRadioButton*    x_15;
    QRadioButton*    x_16;


//bool wake_flag;
      signalDataReader_var m_signalReader;
      DDS::GuardCondition_var m_guardCond;

      ListenerDataListener (QPlainTextEdit *m_rec, QRadioButton *y_13, QRadioButton *y_14,
                            QRadioButton *y_15, QRadioButton *y_16) {
          m_guardCond = new DDS::GuardCondition();
          m_closed = false;
          h_send = m_rec;
          x_13  =   y_13;
          x_14  =   y_14;
          x_15  =   y_15;
          x_16  =   y_16;
      }
/* Callback method implementation. */
void on_data_available(DDS::DataReader_ptr parentReader)
THROW_ORB_EXCEPTIONS;
```

My .c file

```
void ListenerDataListener::on_data_available(DDS::DataReader_ptr parentReader)
  THROW_ORB_EXCEPTIONS
{

 DDS::ReturnCode_t status;
 signalSeq msgList;
SampleInfoSeq infoSeq;

for (DDS::ULong j = 0; j < msgList.length(); j++)
  {
  connect(x_13, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(disp1()));//This is where it shows the error
  connect(x_14, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(disp2()));//also here
  connect(x_15, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(disp3()));//and here
  connect(x_13, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(disp4()));//here
```

Comment: And *where* do you get the error? Can you please edit your code to include a comment where the error is?

Comment: sure@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: there you go@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: what is disp1 - 4 ? Can you clean up the code with the not needed stuff removed and the needed things included?

Comment: if you are using qt5 you should also consider changing the `connect` to the new syntax. The error messages you get there are more verbos and they catch more errors: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @Hayt Yes I am using Qt5, I have no problems using it in another thread of the same program (same syntx). disp1-4 are my functions which wants to disply data onto a qtextbox

Comment: It looks like it wants to use the `connect(...)` function for sockets. Do you have a socket related header included somewhere here? As mentioined. using the modern connect() syntax may help this problem

Comment: yes you are write, it is.... I also figured it out and trying to use QObject::Connect(............)
where it is showing this
33: error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QRadioButton*&, const char*, ListenerDataListener*, const char*)'
       QObject::connect(x_13, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(disp1()));
                                                                        ^

Comment: have you tried the new syntax? the old connect etc. did a lot of macro magic which may result in such errors.

Comment: i'm not sure about this syntax, I'm using the same syntax in another thread of the same project. It is prefectly working.... :(

Comment: yeah probably because you don't include the socket header file in that cpp file so you don't get the conflicts. Just try ;)

Comment: how do i refer to "this " in connect statement. I am implementing the connect in a call back method

Comment: The receiver must also derive from `Qobject`. Does it?